# Java Swing executing gFortran code

Tags: java, swing, fortran, gfortran

I was wondering is there anyway for Java / Swing code to execute gFortran program on ubuntu/linux platform?

Anyone has some idea on how this could be done ?

Comment: yes that's possible, please amend your post and change JSwing to Swing, please read http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Swing really has nothing to do with your problem I think other than your needing to take care to make any gFortran calls on a background thread.

Comment: meaning that , there are 2 ways of doing it
1. Java executes gFortran code?
2. Jave executes C code which executes gFortran code ?

Comment: yes first ways is correct, 1) if your gFortran code is correctly and can returns desired value, 2 ) looks like as complicated way, why invoke C/C#/C++ code via JNI/JNA and then to the Fortran preprocesor, (sorry for next words) looks like as stupitidy, 3) are you dissatisfied with http://sourceforge.net/projects/f2j/ 4) better would be check another alternatives in Google,

Comment: @mKorbel, thanks for the input. I am not concern how the gFortran code looks like or how it runs. All i know about the code is it reads and input file and converts it into an output. The gFortran code that was given to me requires approx 2 hours to execute.

I just want to know what's the best way to execute gFortran code from Java interface and the alternatives of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is to run a separate program using [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to start a [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) consisting of your fortran code. The following is an example of this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
  String[] env = {"/path/to/program"};
  Process proc = rt.exec("your_program", env);
  System.out.println("return value: " + proc.waitFor());
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.err.println(ex);
}
```

The above code will execute /path/to/program/your_program and wait for it to finish and then read off the return code.

Alternatively, you could write some information to *stdout* and read that from your java program:

```
import java.io.*;
...
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
  String[] env = {"/path/to/program"}; 
  Process proc = rt.exec("your_program", env);
  System.out.println("return value: " + proc.waitFor());

  InputStream stream = proc.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
  while (reader.ready()) {
    // Do something with the data here.
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
  }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.err.println(ex);
}
```

If you need to supply the external program with arguments you pass them as an array of strings. As an example, if I wanted to run `ls -lh /etc/` that is what the following code does:

```
  String[] cmd = {"ls", "-lh", "/etc/"};
  String[] env = {"/bin/"};
  Process proc = rt.exec(cmd, env);
```

You could also try using [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to communicate with C/C++ code which can interface with fortran.

Comment: If you want to use JNI, make sure you use [iso_c_binding](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html). Otherwise you have to study fortran name mangling.

Comment: i really have no clue where to start !

Comment: @user793260: The easiest thing to do would be to run an external program from your java program. Do you need a response from the fortran program? One way is to incorporate the result in the return code of the program (when it terminates), another is to write some result to a file or your could establish a socket connection between your java program and fortran program.

Comment: @user793260: Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: i was given a project where there's a massive gfortran code which will take about 2 hours to execute. What it does was process an input file into an output file.  The output file contains data which can be plotted to a XYZ 3D graph.

My job was to create an interface which creates the input file, run the gFortran code with the created input file, reads the output file with the interface and converts it into a XYZ 3D Graph in a linux env.

The only difficulty right now is the correct implementation of using Java and executing gFortran code.

Comment: @Melvin: Try looking at my edited post above. There's an example of how you can supply arguments to a program (your gFortran program) you want to execute. So you invoke the program and see what the return code is; `0` is typically "success" and other values mean "failure" of some kind. If it's `0` then you read in the generated file and do your post-processing then.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your guidance, i will keep this page bookmarked as i am still caught up other assignments.